# How to display python variable values in Django template without using Models?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and am facing this problem currently. I want to calculate the area and perimeter of a circle and post the result in the Django Template. I used a form to allow a user to input any number which will be considered as the radius. Using the POST method, it will process it and output me the area and perimeter (in views.py file). However, I'm not able to display the area and perimeter values in my Django template HTML page. The only values I store in my model is the **radius** value inputted by the user. How do display the area and perimeter without using models?

HTML page for form radius input: insert_radius.html 
HTML page for displaying output: view_result.html

Please do help.

**myapp/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Circle(models.Model):
    radius = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.radius)
```

**myapp/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import Circle

class CircleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Circle
        fields = ["radius"]
```

**myapp/views.py**

```
import math
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView, ListView
from myapp.forms import CircleForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from myapp.models import Circle
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class CircleView(CreateView):
    form_class = CircleForm
    template_name = 'insert_radius.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            radius =  form.cleaned_data.get('radius')
            area = math.pi * (radius ** 2)
            perimeter = 2 * math.pi * radius
            print(radius, area, perimeter)
            form.save()
            final= {"radius" : radius, "area" : area, "perimeter": 
 perimeter}
            context= {'final': final}
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("view_result"))
            return render(request, "view_result.html", context) 


        else:
            form = self.form_class()

class ViewResult(ListView):
    template_name = 'view_result.html'
    model = Circle
```

**templates/insert_radius.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Insert radius </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Enter radius </h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**templates/view_result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> View result </title>
</head>
<body>

    Area: {{final.area}} <br>
    Perimeter: {{final.perimeter}} <br>

</body>
</html>
```

**myapp/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import HomeView, CircleView, ViewResult

urlpatterns = [
   path('home', HomeView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
   path('insert_radius', CircleView.as_view(), name = 'insert_radius'),
   path('view_result', ViewResult.as_view(), name = 'view_result'),
]
```

Comment: remove `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("view_result"))`, why is it required?

Comment: @RajanSharma: the *Post/Redirect/Get* pattern?

Comment: @RajanSharma if the input is successful in insert_radius.html, it will redirect me to the view_result.html page

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `CircleView` has too much boilerplate code. In fact the main use case of a `CreateView` is let Django handle creating a view:

```
# app/views.py

from django.urls import reverse

class CircleView(CreateView):
    form_class = CircleForm
    template_name = 'insert_radius.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('view_result', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Next we can add some functionality to the circle to calculate the perimeter:

```
# app/models.py

from math import pi

class Circle(models.Model):
    radius = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*pi*self.radius

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.radius)
```

The `ViewResult` is here a `DetailView`, since it will show the details of a database record. We furthermore need to add a primary key parameter to that url pattern:

```
# app/urls.py
```

from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import HomeView, CircleView, ViewResult

urlpatterns = [
   path('home', HomeView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
   path('insert_radius', CircleView.as_view(), name = 'insert_radius'),
   path('view_result/**<int:pk>**', ViewResult.as_view(), name = 'view_result'),
]

Finally in our views we, can then make `ViewResult` a detailview, and rename the circle variable to `final`:

```
# app/views.py

from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from app.models import Circle

class ViewResult(DetailView):
    template_name = 'view_result.html'
    model = Circle
    context_object_name = 'final'
```

Comment: Oh man, thank you! It works like a charm. But one question, why did you add @property in models.py? And what does boilerplate code mean?

Comment: @Retro_coder: do you know what `@property` does? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: I don't understand the docs much. Can you tell me what it does, in a nutshell?